# Styling each result of an fgets($file) list differently, is it possible?

Tags: php, fgets

G'day, first post so here we go. Very open to suggestions as I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I want with the type of coding I am using. Kinda new/rusty to coding, been a LOOOONG time.

Purpose of current coding:

I have a `.txt` file with a list of file names (map names to be exact for my situation, each on it's own line) that is constantly being changed and modified as we `add/remove` maps. I am using a script on a `.php` page to parse the contents of that file and display the results on a webpage. The script outputs each map name to a variable that is wrapped in an `href` tag, which results in a link to download that particular map. This continues until all maps have been created in a list, each as a link to download that map.

Problem I am having:

I do not wish some `maps/entries` to be created as links, and only as text. Is there a way to filter the results of an `fgets()` and style them different based on value? So like map1-map4 all get turned into download links but map5 does not, then map6 and on continue to be download links.

Current script/code being used:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("maplists/dodgeball.ini", "r");

while (!feof($file)) {
    $dbmapname[] = fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);


foreach ($dbmapname as $dbmap){
echo "<a href='http://www.mydownloadurl.com/fastdl/maps/" . $dbmap . ".bsp.bz2'>$dbmap</a><br />";
}
?>
```

Coding revised thanks to help below. Here is my current coding to produce what I was looking for:

```
foreach ($dbmapname as $dbmap){
if(!in_array($dbmap, $stockmaps)){
echo "<a href='http://www.mydownloadurl.com/fastdl/maps/" . $dbmap . ".bsp.bz2'>$dbmap</a><br />";
}
else echo $dbmap."<br />";
}
```

I am still having a slight issue though regarding the last entry of the array being forced to be a link regardless if it is in the `$stockmaps` array or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a ton of ways to implement this. Below I've presented a nice general way where you create an array of maps for which you don't want a link and then loop through and print either link or the plain text depending on whether each map is in the list.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("maplists/dodgeball.ini", "r");

while (!feof($file)) {
    $dbmapname[] = trim(fgets($file));
}
fclose($file);

$nolink = array( $dbmapname[4] ); //fifth map

foreach ($dbmapname as $dbmap){
  if(!in_array($dbmap, $nolink)){
    echo "<a href='http://www.mydownloadurl.com/fastdl/maps/" . $dbmap . ".bsp.bz2'>$dbmap</a><br />";
  }
  else echo $dbmap."<br />";
}
}
?>
```

You can add item to the filter based on whatever criteria you want

```
//Add item 2 to the list
$nolink[] = $dbmapname[1];

//Add all items after item 20 to the list
$nolink = array_merge($nolink, array_slice($dbmapname, 20));

//Don't link a specific set of maps
$nolink = array('bad_map', 'another_map_not_to_show');
```

Comment: If I knew the map name I wanted to NOT link could I use something along the lines of:

    `code`$nolink[] = $dbmapname[ctf_2fort];`code`

and that way that particular map, since I know the name but not exactly where it falls in the list, WILL NOT be listed as a link?

Comment: That's the right idea. If you have specific of map names to not show it would look like:

$nolink = array('ctf_2fort', 'another_map_to_not_show');

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give this a try and see how it works out. I appreciate the time and help thus far!

Comment: I just tested the code and the results were as follows: If I used the `array( $dbmapname[4] )` coding it works, but if I used `array('ctf_2fort')` it does not seem to recognize the entry. Perhaps there is something I am doing wrong? OR is it just because my coding isn't written properly for it to actually read the value of the array like that?

Either way I am VERY thankful you gave me atleast one option to work with. Curious to see why the other method of using map name itself wouldn't work but still VERY thankful.

Comment: It still ought to work under those circumstances. However it is important that the text you put in array('ctf_2fort') is the exact text in the array. You could try calling print_r($dbmapname); and looking at the output to see what exactly is stored in your array

Comment: Everything looks right but just doesn't function. I'm just gonna chock it up as some part of my code is not written correctly to allow me to read the array using those proper names. I will try to use the other method `$dbmapname[4]` etc etc for now. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: I found somewhat of a work around (don't know if it's considered a butchered job or not) implementing your coding from above. I used your coding: `if(!in_array($dbmap, $nolink)){` but instead of referencing `$nolink` I just created a new text file (named `stockmaps` containing the map names I do not want linked. I then modified the code to read `if(!in_array($dbmap, $stockmaps)){` and it worked great minus the last entry being forced as a link regardless of it being in the stockmaps array or not. I updated my OP with this info, near the bottom. Any ideas on the cause?

Comment: Hearing that, the problem is that your program is leaving the trailing newlines at the end of each map name. That is why the text strings arent matching the names loaded from the file. i.e. the name in the file is "ctf_2fort\n" and the string is just "ctf_2fort"

Comment: switch out "$dbmapname[] = fgets($file);" for "$dbmapname[] = trim(fgets($file));" and everything should work. I'll add that to the answer. The trim will remove any excess whitespace.